# Mock mobile user agent using Mocha

Tags: unit-testing, automation, mocha.js, user-agent

I'm writing unit tests using mocha, and I'm having trouble mocking a mobile user agent.
I have the following test :

```
   describe('GET /android/update', function () {
    it('should update android', function (done) {
            var self = this;
        self.sess.get('/android/update')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200, done);
      });
    });
```

To get the test to pass, I need to mock a mobile useragent. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. if someone needs it, just add the following :

`.set('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G920V Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36')`